# Handling paginated links using a MobX store and React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, mobx

New to both React and MobX, so any advice would be appreciated! I'm trying to build a component that accepts both "store" and "pageNum" as props in order to automatically populate the number of pages from the PaginationStore.

For the PaginationStoreLink component, it's pulling from ReactStrap's PaginationLink:

```
const PaginationStorePageLink = ({ store, pageNum }) => (observer(({ PaginationStore }) => (
  <PaginationLink className={styles.pagination} onClick={this.props.store.goToPage(this.props.pageNum)} />
)));
```

The PaginationStorePageLink component is wrapped by PaginationStoreLinks:

```
const PaginationStoreLinks = ({ store }) => (observer(({ clusterStore }) => (
  <PaginationLink>
    <PaginationStorePageLink store={store} />
  </PaginationLink>
)));
```

How do I pass in the Store correctly?

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an arrow operator is missing:

```
const PaginationStorePageLink = ({ store, pageNum }) => 
    (observer(({ PaginationStore }) => (
      <PaginationLink 
           className={styles.PaginationLink} 
           onClick={store.goToPage(pageNum} 
       />
   )
));
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped with the initial error I was seeing! Do you have any tips for interlinking the two components?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "interlinking".  Can you elaborate?  I think the way you're passing the props should work fine.  I made a small edit to the code in my resposne.  If using destructuring, then you don't need `this.props.`.